# How can I fix file corruption while trying to reduce memory usage of a memory mapped file?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, memory, memory-leaks

I have the following code below, it is attempting to read from the content of a HTTPResponseMessage and trying to write it to a memory mapped file. My first attempt of doing this (using a memory mapped file view stream outside the loop and writing async from the buffer to the stream, it can be found [here](https://github.com/gregyjames/OctaneDownloader/blob/master/OctaneEngine/Clients/OctaneClient.cs)) worked perfectly however, the memory usage of the program was was increased significantly:
[image: Memory usage using outside view stream]

As you can see the unmanaged memory is massive because the viewstream contains the entire content of the part of the file being downloaded. The solution below fixes the memory usage issue:
[image: Memory usage using inside stream view accessor]
Almost a 68% memory reduction at the peak unfortunately it is corrupting the downloaded file now. My question is what am I doing wrong here? Is my calculation of the accessor incorrect? bytesReadOverall is just a long that contains the number of bytes written total. The part being downloaded is specified in a value tuple (start,end) named piece.

```
while (true)
        {
            var buffer = _memPool.Rent(_config.BufferSize);
            var bytesRead = streamToRead.Read(buffer, 0, _config.BufferSize);
            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            var streams = _mmf.CreateViewAccessor(piece.Item1+bytesReadOverall, bytesRead, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Write);
            streams.WriteArray(0, buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            streams.Flush();
            bytesReadOverall += bytesRead;
            child?.Tick((int)bytesReadOverall);
            _memPool.Return(buffer, true);
        }
```

Comment: Probably won't solve your problem, but couldn't you just use [Stream.CopyTo(stream)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto?view=net-7.0) instead of having the explicit buffering that you do?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Doesn't Stream.CopyTo allocate another buffer internally? I noticed that the second parameter is an int for bufferSize. I like manually allocating the buffer because this way I can ensure that only one buffer is used for reading the stream and writing.

Comment: Yes, I believe that is correct, but it would free your code from having to manage it, that's all.